How to maintain a carbon steel skillet?
I am familiar with maintaining cast iron. Is maintaining carbon steel have similar rules of thumb?

Avoid abrasive materials
After cleaning, wipe and heat up and apply layer of oil


I'm no expert, and only have one carbon steel skillet, but it seems to be rather similar... but the warnings against pre-heating seem to be even more important (but mostly seem to be to prevent burning off the seasoning, not causing it to bow and be ruined)
